# Minimum two rows using column-width with inline-blocks

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to separate inline-blocks into columns, starting with one item in each column. Instead, it's giving me two blocks in a column initially. What can I do to alter the behavior?

http://jsfiddle.net/fuqrwe64/10/

```
<style>
.container {
  background: #f99;
  column-width: 130px;
}

.item {
  background: #9f9;
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: monospace;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `column-count` CSS property

```
.item{
column-count:3;
}
```

and you can use `column-gap` property  to set the width if you want to set it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  .container {
  background: #f99;
  width:280px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  background: #9f9;
  width: 130px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

I hope this is what you want. if not just let me know the exact requirement.

Comment: This definitely also gets to the right behavior, but I have to use column-width/column-count instead because we want the items to cascade rather than occupy one item per row.